# Rails 4, every time I click some links, why resources load many times?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a junior rails developer. I meet a question now.

Here is the thing.
Every time I click a link to change web page, my browser load the resource files, and never release.

e.g.
[image]

I hope every time I click a link, the resources don't load every time.
Hope someone can help me. Thanks very much!!

Comment: Have you added require .tree and loaded all js in Application.js

Comment: i guess in development mode, your whole page loads every time. Thats why you can make change to your code and refresh page to see your changes. In production it doesnt happen. In config -> environments -> development.rb you can see `config.cache_classes = false` .. make it to `true` if you want to enable cache. Is this what you are looking for >

Comment: @Hemali Hi, this is my Application.js file   `// about supported directives.
//
//= require jquery
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require foundation
//= require turbolinks
//= require_tree .

$(function(){ $(document).foundation(); });`    I don't how to do .

Comment: @RahulSambari In fact, under the production mode. My configuration has `config.cache_classes = true`, but today, I deploy the production to my VPS, I got lots of load resources errors. This is my personal wiki [link](http://wiki.ohcoder.com).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you added `javascript_include_tag :application` to the `body` tag instead of `head`.
So Turbolinks fetch it again on every request.

Comment: maybe that's not. I put the code into head tag.     `<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />

    <title><%= content_for?(:title) ? yield(:title) : "wiki" %></title>

    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application" %>
    <%= javascript_include_tag "vendor/modernizr" %>
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  </head>`

Comment: There is no application.js, check your page source in browser. Also you can check `initiator` for this scripts in `network` tab (in chrome).

Comment: oh, I know what you mean. I add the Foundation css library, so in the <head> tag there is no have "application.js"link, instead of put in the end of the <body> tag. Do you think is that problem? if it is so, what should I do? where should I write the `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` code? Thanks! Can I put it into the <head> tag?

Comment: cool, thank you very much! I tried to put the `<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>` code into <head> tag. It looks fine, now just load one time. But under the XHRs menu and the images menu still increate every time click the page link. Do you think this is normal? how to deal with the images?

Comment: It's Turbolinks, you can read more about it in its repo. It speeds up page load, but if you don't want it just remove `require turbolinks` from your `application.js`

Comment: Ok. Thanks very much! It looks fine now. http://wiki.ohcoder.com . Still a ttf type file can not be loaded, so in the next, I need to fix it. Thanks again. ^_^